# WPF Drop event is firing twice

Tags: wpf, xaml, events, drag-and-drop, event-handling

***2nd Edit***

so removing the Panel.ZIndex properties from the control template resolved this issue for me, giving me 1 drop event.
including them triggers two drop events.
can any one answer me why though?
id love to know why z index ?

***Original Question :***

I am trying to add a custom object (state) to a canvas called MainCanvas on the MainWindow.
I am trying to drag a state object from a wrap panel and drop it onto the canvas.

the code works but there are two items being added.
I know there are two because I can move the two item around the canvas.

I have searched existing answers and added e.Handled=true, but still adds two items
I tried using Drop event and PreviewDrop Event on MainCanvas, no difference.

Cam someone help as to how I can make it so that only 1 item gets added?

the maincanvas exists at design time
a new state is created at runtime at the drop event.

Here is the OnMouseMove handler for the state

```
protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseMove(e);
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this);
        if (parent as WrapPanel != null)
        {
            DataObject dragData = new DataObject();
            dragData.SetData(DataFormats.StringFormat, this.ItemType);
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, dragData, DragDropEffects.Copy);
            

        }
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Within the Code Behind I have set the following events for the canvas:

```
private void MainCanvas_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))

        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    else
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
    e.Handled = true;
}

private void MainCanvas_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var itemType = e.Data.GetData(typeof(string));

    switch (itemType)
    {
        case "state":
            var pos = e.GetPosition(this.MainCanvas);
            State item = new State();
            item.Template = (ControlTemplate)FindResource("StateViewModelControlTemplate");
            this.MainCanvas.Children.Add(item);
            Canvas.SetLeft(item, pos.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(item, pos.Y);
            e.Handled = true;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Finally here is the xaml for the Main Canvas

```
<Canvas x:Name="MainCanvas" x:Name="MainCanvas"
                                    DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
                                    Background="#666" 
                                    Height="600" 
                                    Margin="4" 
                                    AllowDrop="True" 
                                    DragEnter="MainCanvas_DragEnter" 
                                    Drop="MainCanvas_Drop"/>
```

Edit:

ok so after lupus' response i went back and reconstructed everything from scratch in a separate temp project

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="StateViewModelControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type vm:State}">
    <Grid Width="100" Height="60">
    
    <!--
    If I comment out the following Thumb 
    the drop event will only trigger once
    If i leave it in then it triggers twice
    
    Move Thumb is derived from thumb
    -->
        <local:MoveThumb Panel.ZIndex="99"
                         x:Name="StateViewModelMoveThumb" 
                         DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                         Opacity="0"/>

        <Border Panel.ZIndex="98" 
                Margin="4" 
                Padding="4" 
                BorderBrush="white" 
                BorderThickness="2" 
                CornerRadius="5">
            <Border.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF59C7D4" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF075A64" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF00626E" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>
            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{TemplateBinding StateName}"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>

</ControlTemplate>
```

By the way what I trying to do is very loosely based on the following article: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22952/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-1

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? We are experiencing the Drop event firing twice for a TabControl with an overridden template where I have placed the drop event specifically on one element (and there are no other drop handlers). The TabPanel has a ZIndex property set and I tried removing that and it didn't resolve like yours did

Comment: It's an age ago, but from memory it's the difference between drop and preview drop... and the fact that each event travels differently.... idid get the code to work... but I'm onlyba hobby coder and this was ages ago.... ill find it and get back to you.

Comment: I have found the code in question and added my own answer, I hope the code below helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I eventually got this working and here is how

Here is the front end xaml on the mainwindow

```
    <cc:DiagramCanvas x:Name="MainCanvas"                         
                        DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
                        Margin="0" 
                        MinHeight="450"
                        AllowDrop="True" Background="White">
                </cc:DiagramCanvas>
```

Here is the custom canvas object and the drag drop handler

```
    public class DiagramCanvas : Canvas
    {
        public DiagramCanvas()
        {
            this.Drop += DoDrop;
            this.DragEnter += MainCanvas_DragEnter;
        }

        readonly MainWindow mainWin = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;

        #region works dont touch
        public void DoDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            var mainWin = (MainWindow)App.Current.MainWindow;
            DragDropHandler<StateVM>.Instance.Drop(sender, e);
        }


        private void MainCanvas_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))

                e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
            else
                e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        #endregion
    //other code here
    }
```

Here is the drag drop handler singleton

```
    public sealed class DragDropHandler<T> where T : Control
    {
        #region singleton
        private static DragDropHandler<T> instance = null;
        private static readonly object padlock = new object();

        DragDropHandler()
        {

        }


        public static DragDropHandler<T> Instance
        {
            get
            {
                lock (padlock)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                    {
                        instance = new DragDropHandler<T>();
                    }
                    return instance;
                }
            }
            private set
            {
                instance = value;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        public static bool IsDragging { get; set; }
        public static WrapPanel AllowedDragSource { get; set; }
        readonly MainWindow mainWin = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;


        public static void CreateInstance(WrapPanel allowedSource)
        {
            if (DragDropHandler<T>.IsDragging == false)
            {
                instance = new DragDropHandler<T>();
                DragDropHandler<T>.AllowedDragSource = allowedSource;
            }
        }

        public void Drag(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender as T == null
                || mainWin.Radio_EditStates.IsChecked == false
                || e.LeftButton != MouseButtonState.Pressed
                || IsDragging == true)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                return;
            }

            var item = (T)sender;

            if (Control.ReferenceEquals(item.Parent, AllowedDragSource) == false)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                return;
            }

            IsDragging = true;
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(((StateVM)sender), new DataObject(((StateVM)sender)), DragDropEffects.Copy);
            IsDragging = false;

            e.Handled = true;
        }

        public void Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            var mainWin = (MainWindow)App.Current.MainWindow;

            if (IsDragging)
            {
                //TODO: Switch here to handle different shapes               

                var pos = e.GetPosition(mainWin.MainCanvas);
                //
                




                Canvas.SetLeft(item, pos.X.RoundDownTo10());
                Canvas.SetTop(item, pos.Y.RoundDownTo10());
                //update  main win observalbe collections to inclue the item dropped
                
                IsDragging = false;
                e.Handled = true;
                DestroyInstance();
            }
        }

        private static void DestroyInstance()
        {
            DragDropHandler<T>.Instance = null;
        }
    }
```

Here is the on mouse move code for the item you are dragging

```
    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseMove(e);
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && Control.ReferenceEquals(this.Parent, mainWin.libraryContainer))
            {
                DragDropHandler<StateVM>.CreateInstance(mainWin.libraryContainer);
                if (DragDropHandler<StateVM>.Instance != null)
                {
                    DragDropHandler<StateVM>.Instance.Drag(this, e);
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, and I cannot reproduce your issue. Changes:

```
private void MainCanvas_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
 var itemType = e.Data.GetData(typeof(string));

 switch (itemType)
 {
      var pos = e.GetPosition(this.MainCanvas);
      Border item = new Border()
      {
            Width = 10,
            Height = 10,
            Background = Brushes.Red
      };
      //item.Template = (ControlTemplate)FindResource("StateViewModelControlTemplate");
      this.MainCanvas.Children.Add(item);
        ...
}

protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnMouseMove(e);
  if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
  {
        DataObject dragData = new DataObject();
        dragData.SetData(DataFormats.StringFormat, "state");
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, dragData, DragDropEffects.Copy);
  }
  e.Handled = true;
}
```

and in xaml,

```
<Window ...
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <Canvas x:Name="MainCanvas" Grid.Column="0"
             DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
             Background="#666" 
             Height="600" 
             Margin="4" 
             AllowDrop="True" 
             DragEnter="MainCanvas_DragEnter" 
             Drop="MainCanvas_Drop"/>

     <Grid Grid.Column="1" Background="Red"/>
</Grid>
```

Have not touch the other piece of code. Everytime I drag from the Grid to the Canvas, I get one Border item at the drop position.

So maybe the problem is not in the code you posted, but in the code left out or commented.